# Getting Order of Particular Customer

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, customer, rest-api

How to get customer orders on the base of customer token in magento 2?Please help me.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

```
Url: http://192.168.1.74/B2B/Magento/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[pageSize]=25&searchCriteria[currentPage]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=128&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=customer_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq

  method : GET
```

**Headers**

```
Authorization :: Bearer <Admintokenvalue>
```

Comment: I want to access orders without using admin token.

Comment: It will be not possible using that service as it need admin token according to ACL.xml. so write anonymous service using the same logic

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get accesstoken of admin and then needs to call order api with passing that AccessToken.

Code for get admin accesstoken :

```
$userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
$ch = curl_init("http://yourwebsiteurl/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);
```

Get order details :

```
$ch = curl_init("http://yourwebsiteurl/index.php/rest/V1/orders/1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

Comment: without admin token,it is possible?

Comment: Can, try this code : https://domain.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[f‌​ilter_groups][0][fil‌​ters][0][field]=cust‌​omer_email&searchCri‌​teria[filter_groups]‌​[0][filters][0][valu‌​e]=aaa@google.com&se‌​archCriteria[filter_‌​groups][0][filters][‌​0][condition_type]=e‌​q&searchCriteria[fil‌​ter_groups][1][filte‌​rs][0][field]=status‌​&searchCriteria[filt‌​er_groups][1][filter‌​s][0][value]=pending‌​&searchCriteria[filt‌​er_groups][1][filter‌​s][0][condition_type‌​]=eq

Comment: it show "message":"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources","parameters":{"resources":"Magento_Sales::sales".

Comment: you changed the example of 'aaa@google.com' ?

Comment: Yes, i will change,but showing same response Consumer is not authorized.